# How to create input formatting attributive directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new in angularjs. I want to create custom directive that delete zeroes in . For example if I will type 00014 i will have 14 in input field. 
I already have some code but I am not sure that it is correct:

```
(function () {
angular.module('issuetrackerApp')
    .directive('validateTime', validateTime);
function validateTime() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            validateTime: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '...'
    };
  }
});
```

HTML

```
 <input type=number>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange event handler to truncate the leading zeros

```
 scope.value.replace(/^0+/, '');
```

Here is an example of it.

```js
console.clear();

var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});


app.directive("textbox", function(){
  return {
    require: "?ngModel",
    template: "<input ng-model='value' ng-change='onChange()'>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
      if (!ngModel) return;
      
      scope.onChange = function(){
      
        scope.value = scope.value.replace(/^0+/, '');
       
      };
      
      ngModel.$render = function(){
        scope.value = ngModel.$modelValue;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-form="form1" ng-app="test">
    
    <pre><textbox name="editor" ng-model="foo" minlength="3"></textbox></pre>
    {{value}}
    <hr>
    
  </div>
```